# Overrided broadcast(Object message, GwtAtmosphereResource resource) method in Atmosphere with GWT not working

Tags: gwt, atmosphere

We are trying to handle a scenario that when a user in quitting a room ,we send a message using MetaBroadcaster to all room .We implemented this feature by override broadcast method of     AtmosphereGwtHandler .

The feature is good when we testing in development mode, but when we test it in Jetty8 production mode, telling by log, the override method is void which never get called.

So anybody know what's wrong with it, or do we have a better solution to this feature.
 here is our code snippet:

```
public class ChatHandler extends AtmosphereGwtHandler { 
    ...
    @Override
    public void broadcast(Object message, GwtAtmosphereResource resource) {

        MsgType msgtype=((ChatMessage)message).getMsgtype();
        if(msgtype==MsgType.Broad){
            MetaBroadcaster.getDefault().broadcastTo(((ChatMessage)message).getChanel(), message);
            System.out.println("Doing to all room);
        }else{
            super.broadcast(message, resource);
            System.out.println("Doing to myself);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be of help if you posted code snippets to allow other developers to make sense of your question. http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0):

Can't really give an answer on the info provided.

Where have you configured your handler?
web.xml or atmosphere.xml

What servlet are you using Meteor/Atmosphere?
What version of Atmosphere?